# Type Conversion for data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have a question. I have 2 class same properties. Example:

```
Pencil {Name,Price}
Pencil1{Name,Price}
```

Date comes "Pencil" list type. But i want return data type "Pencil1". Can I do withount loop?

Comment: why you think that loop is bad?

Comment: Problem is performance. I working very large data.

Comment: so if you need apply function for each item in list no method without loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ, but **it will perform loop internaly** anyway:

```
List<Pencil> input = GetPencil();
List<Pencil1> output = input.Select(x => new Pencil1 { Name = x.Name, Price = x.Price }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go bro..

```
public class Pencil
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }

}
public class Pencil1 : Pencil
{

}

List<Pencil1> list = new List<Pencil1>();
List<Pencil> listCopy = list.OfType<Pencil>().ToList();
```

you are done now.

Comment: Thanks, but no relationship in classes.